# Cordova deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds in sencha touch 2 projects

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, phonegap

I am facing a problem when I build android and ios application after upgrading Cordova from 2.8 to 5.0.0 in sencha touch 2 projects. Android console prints a message like "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds" and "Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady".
Can somebody please suggest something.

Versions:
Sencha Touch : 2.4.2
Cordova : 5.0.0
Cordova Jar : cordova-2.8.1.jar
Android : 4.4.2
Android API : 19

Thank you,
Som

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could post the code of your `index.html` file -- without the code, it's impossible to tell for certain what the problem is.

The most likely cause is that you've not included `cordova.js` in your `index.html`. Try adding this line to your `index.html`:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Don't worry that `cordova.js` doesn't exist in your code base, the file is generated at build time by Cordova.

I recently encountered this same issue, but in my case `cordova.js` was already included. Eventually what worked for me was a simple `remove` and `add` of the `ios` platform:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

It had been quite a while since I had completely re-built the `ios` platform and other major changes had taken place during that time (Cordova upgrade, XCode upgrade, etc). It's possible that my `config.xml` or existing `ios` build was somehow incompliant with the latest Cordova requirements.

Comment: Thank you. That got resolved, it was a problem with building platform.
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios

Comment: Sure Thank you!!